# How to add string to the front of Text file

Tags: c#, streamreader

This is the text file read by the `StreamReader`.

```
500, 120, 60, 0, 350
100, 230, 0, 50, 0
0, 75, 0, 0, 220
3000, 400, 600, 35, 0
350, 200, 100, 80, 250
0, 285, 325, 150, 75
```

I want to add cities in front of each line, such that it reads like this:

```
Atlanta:  500, 120, 60, 0, 350
Baltimore: 100, 230, 0, 50, 0
Chicago:0, 75, 0, 0, 220
Denver: 3000, 400, 600, 35, 0
ELY: 350, 200, 100, 80, 250
Fargo: 0, 285, 325, 150, 75
```

Here's the current code block.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("inventory.txt");
String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ReadLine()` instead? Provided your lines are separated by line breaks. You then could just call `line = "(City) " + line` and write it to console.

Comment: Basic idea is: read the file line by line; as you do so, for each line modify as desired, and write that line out to a new file. See marked duplicates for examples of that sort of operation.

Answer (score 0):

If each line is separated by "\n" you could do:

```
string[] temp = line.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for (int i = 0; i < cityNames.Length; i++)
{
    temp[i] += cityNames[i];
}
string result = string.Join(",\n", temp);
return result.Remove(result.Length - 3, 2);
```